# Define style to HTML for webView in Android

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I want to populate webView with HTML by using the following:

```
String str = "<html>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<style> \n" +
            "h3 {\"font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:1.3;\"} \n" +
            "p {\"font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:1.3;\"} \n" +
        "</style> \n" +
        "<h3> Open-Source licenses</h3>\n" +
        "<p> A huge thanks from all of us at to the great people behind the great programs listed below.</p>\n" +
        "<ul>\n" +
        "<li>Asynchronous Http Client for Android</li>\n" +
        "<li>Glide</li>\n" +
        "<li>Google Play Service</li>\n" +
        "<li>Gson</li>\n" +
        "<li>Picasso</li>\n" +
        "</ul>\n" +
        "<hr>" +
        "<h3>Asynchronous Http Client for Android</h3>\n" +
        "<p><a href=\"https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http\">https://github.com/android-async-http/android-async-http</a></p> \n" +
        "<p>Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software<br>distributed under the License is distributed on an &quot;AS IS&quot; BASIS,<br>WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.<br>See the License for the specific language governing permissions and<br>limitations under the License.</p>\n" +
        "</body></html>";

wb_OpenSource.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, str, "text/html", "utf-8", null );
```

However, it seems like the style does not make any difference.

Any way to make it work instead of adding style to each line?

UPDATE:

As was suggest below, I created a .css file that looks as follows:

```
#topHeader {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;line-height:1.3;
}

#regHeader {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:1.3;
}

#topText {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.3;
}

#regText {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:1.3;
}

#links {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:1.3;
}
```

And changed my HTML to be:

```
"<body>" +
"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"cssStyles.css\"> \n" +
"<h3 id=\"topHeader\"> Open-Source licenses</h3>\n" +
"<p id=\"topText\"> A huge thanks from all of us at to the great people behind the great programs listed below</p>\n" +
"<ul>\n" +
"<li id=\"regText\"> Asynchronous Http Client for Android </li>\n" +
"<li id=\"regText\"> ExpandableTextView Android Arsenal </li>\n" +
```

and

```
wb_OpenSource.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file://android_asset/cssStyles.css", str, "text/html", "utf-8", null );
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate `.css` file for styling the elements. Place the .css file in the assets folder and include it in your html code.

Now load the HTML in the webview like below:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset", HTML_STRING, "text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Could you please give more details? I created an .css file and placed it in assets. Do I need to change my HTML_STRING and place link to the .css in it or because I mentioned it in the file:///android_asset it is already included? Because now it is not working for me.